# jar created with gradle - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a project managed with gradle wrapper; this project generate a war file that will be run in wildfly.

Now i have to create an additional jar file, so i create a new task

```
task issue2266Jar(type: Jar, description: "crea issue2266.jar") {
    group 'flowManager'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'it.gpi.flowmanager2.database.issue2266.RearrangeKey'
    }
    baseName = 'issue2266'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

that create jar, but when i run with

```
java -jar issue2266.jar
```

i get the message "Could not find or load main class: it.gpi.flowmanager2.database.issue2266.RearrangeKey"

in the jar file the RearrangeKy.class exist and is in issue2266.jar\it\gpi\flowmanager2\database\issue2266\ folder

if i make the same things in a new project all work
can someone help ?

this is [build.gradle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwuAkjxZtQW466FD2YelIobHaEBWR_Gi/view?usp=sharing)

and this is manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: it.gpi.flowmanager2.database.issue2266.RearrangeKey
```

Comment: Nope, it should be `/it/gpi/flowmanager2/database/issue2266/RearrangeKey.class`

Comment: @GyroGearless, in jar the path is issue2266.jar\it\gpi\flowmanager2\database\issue2266\RearrangeKey.class

Comment: @GyroGearless
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-4r2VTtlFQ5zAZNXtPUOyxTHDkRZDRBj/view?usp=sharing